# Add a component as props inside a Route with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Having the following code:

```
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

export function MyComponent({ list }: MyComponentProps) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={list[0].url} component={<NextComponent />} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I want to load a different component on that route.

Version of `react-router-dom` is 5.2.0.

This code is not working, it appears a red line under `<Route path...` stating this:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'typeof Route'.ts(2365)
(alias) class Route<T extends {} = {}, Path extends string = string>
import Route
```

Any ideas?

**LATER EDIT:**

There is an answer stating that replacing that line with `component={NextComponent}` will get rid of the error message. That's true but is it possible to send props to that component in this case?

For example, for `component={<NextComponent someProps={something} />}`  seems possible but not for `component={NextComponent}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v5 you don't specify the `component` prop as a JSX literal (the RRDv6 syntax), just pass a reference to the component.

`component={NextComponent}` instead of `component={<NextComponent />}`

Code

```
export function MyComponent({ list }: MyComponentProps) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={list[0].url} component={NextComponent} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If you need to pass along additional props then you must use the `render` prop. This effectively renders an anonymous React component. Don't forgot you may need to also pass along the route props to the rendered components.

```
export function MyComponent({ list }: MyComponentProps) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path={list[0].url}
          render={props => <NextComponent {...props} something={value} />} 
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[Route render methods](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)

Comment: it works like this but is it possible to send props for that component? Something like `component={<NextComponent something={value} />}` ?